# Showing that two functions are different on some interval with differentiation.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Both functions are differentiable at some constant c. I want to show that the two functions are different on at least one interval with a positive lebesgue measure.

I can show that $f’(c)\ne g’(c)$. My guess is it is enough to show that $f(x) \ne g(x)$ on a small neighbourhood of $c$.

Am I correct? If so, how should I argue this properly?

Comment: Not exactly. What prevents $f(c) = g(c)$?

Comment: @bungo but $f(c+\epsilon)$ and $g(c+\epsilon)$ will differ for very small $\epsilon$ if they have different derivative. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG assume $f'(c) > g'(c)$. Let $h(x) = f(x + c) - g(x + c)$. Then $h$ is differentiable at $x=0$, with $h'(0) = f'(c) - g'(c) > 0$.

There are two possibilities:

**Csae 1:** $h(0) \neq 0$

In this case, since $h$ is continuous at zero, we have $h(x) \neq 0$ in some $\epsilon$-neighborhood $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, hence $f(x+c) \neq g(x+c)$ in that neighborhood, or equivalently $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for $x \in (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$.

**Case 1:** $h(0) = 0$

Working from the definition of the derivative, we have
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{h(x)}{x} = h'(0) > 0$$
Hence there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $x$ with $0 < |x| < \epsilon$, we have
$$\left|\frac{h(x)}{x}\right| = \frac{h(x)}{x} > \frac{h'(0)}{2} > 0$$
This means that
$$|h(x)| > \frac{h'(0)}{2}|x| > 0$$
and in particular $h(x) \neq 0$. Referring to the definition of $h$, this means that for $0 < |x| < \epsilon$, we have
$$f(x+c) - g(x+c) \neq 0$$
so $f(x+c) \neq g(x+c)$. Equivalently, $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for all $x \in (c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon) \setminus \{c\}$.